# How to exclude an element in an ordered list in HTML

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I want to skip an `li` element in an ordered list.

This is my code:

```html
<ol style="list-style-type: upper-alpha;">
  <li>ALICI; mal satışına ilişkin mesafeli sözleşmelerde, ürünün kendisine veya gösterdiği adresteki kişi/kuruluşa teslim tarihinden itibaren kanunen 14 (ondört) gün  içerisinde hiçbir hukuki ve cezai sorumluluk üstlenmeksizin ve hiçbir gerekçe göstermeksizin
    malı reddederek sözleşmeden cayma hakkını kullanabilir. Hizmet sunumuna ilişkin mesafeli sözleşmelerde ise, bu süre sözleşmenin imzalandığı tarihten itibaren başlar. Cayma hakkının kullanımından kaynaklanan masraflar SATICI’ya aittir.</li>
  <li>ALICI, mesafeli sözleşmeyi ya da buna karşılık gelen herhangi bir teklifi kabul etmeden önce işbu Ön Bilgilendirme Formu ile SATICI tarafından bilgilendirildiğini peşinen kabul eder.</li>
  <li>Cayma hakkının kullanılması için 14 (ondört) günlük süre içinde SATICI'ya iadeli taahhütlü posta, faks veya eposta ile SATICI’nın yukarıda belirtilen adresine yazılı bildirimde bulunulması gerekmektedir. Ancak ilgili hukuki düzenlemeler gereğince aşağıda
    yazılı mal/hizmetlere ilişkin sözleşmelerde, kullanılmamış/istifade edilmemiş olsa dahi, cayma hakkı bulunmamaktadır: <br /> <br /> ALICI’nın özel istekleri veya onun kişisel ihtiyaçları doğrultusunda üretilen (üzerinde değişiklik ya da ilaveler yapılarak
    kişiye/kişisel ihtiyaçlara özel hale getirilenler dahil) mallar;  niteliği itibariyle geri gönderilmeye elverişli olmayan ve çabuk bozulma tehlikesi olan veya son kullanma tarihi geçme ihtimali olan mallar; ALICI tarafından ambalajı açılmış cd, dvd
    gibi ses veya görüntü kayıtları, yazılım programları ve bilgisayar sarf malzemeleri; fiyatı borsa gibi teşkilatlanmış piyasalarda belirlenen mallar; gazete, dergi gibi yayınlar; bahis ve piyangoya ilişkin hizmetler; genel olarak, elektronik ortamda
    anında ifa edilen tüm hizmetler ve ALICI’ya anında teslim edilen her türlü gayri maddi mallar. Ayrıca, ALICI onayı ile cayma hakkı süresi içinde ifasına başlanan hizmetler ve ilgili mevzuat uyarınca mesafeli satış kapsamı dışında kabul edilen diğer
    mal-hizmetler.</li>
  <li>
    <!--This item should not have an increment counter but next item should have in orderly -->
    <p>
      <ul style="list-style-type: none">
        <li>
          Cayma hakkı süresinin belirlenmesinde;<br />
          <ul style="list-style-type: none">
            <li>Tek sipariş konusu olup ayrı ayrı teslim edilen mallarda, tüketicinin veya tüketici tarafından belirlenen üçüncü kişinin son malı teslim aldığı gün,</li>
            <li>Birden fazla parçadan oluşan mallarda, tüketicinin veya tüketici tarafından belirlenen üçüncü kişinin son parçayı teslim aldığı gün,</li>
            <li>Belirli bir süre boyunca malın düzenli tesliminin yapıldığı sözleşmelerde, tüketicinin veya tüketici tarafından belirlenen üçüncü kişinin ilk malı teslim aldığı gün esas alınır.</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    Cayma hakkının kullanılması halinde,
    <ol style="list-style-type: lower-roman;">
      <li>3. kişiye veya ALICI’ya teslim edilen ürünün faturası, (İade edilmek istenen ürünün faturası kurumsal ise, geri iade ederken kurumun düzenlemiş olduğu iade faturası ile birlikte gönderilmesi gerekmektedir. Faturası kurumlar adına düzenlenen sipariş
        iadeleri İADE FATURASI kesilmediği takdirde tamamlanamayacaktır.)</li>
      <li>İade formu</li>
      <li>İade edilecek ürünlerin kutusu, ambalajı, varsa standart aksesuarları ile birlikte eksiksiz ve hasarsız olarak teslim edilmesi gerekmektedir.</li>
      <li>SATICI, cayma bildiriminin kendisine ulaşmasından itibaren en geç 14 günlük süre içerisinde toplam bedeli ve ALICI’yı borç altına sokan belgeleri ALICI’ya iade etmek ve 20 günlük süre içerisinde malı iade almakla yükümlüdür.</li>
      <li>ALICI’nın kusurundan kaynaklanan bir nedenle malın değerinde bir azalma olursa veya iade imkânsızlaşırsa ALICI kusuru oranında SATICI’nın zararlarını tazmin etmekle yükümlüdür.</li>
      <li>Cayma hakkının kullanılması nedeniyle SATICI tarafından düzenlenen kampanya limit tutarının altına düşülmesi halinde kampanya kapsamında faydalanılan indirim miktarı iptal edilir.</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

I have 5 `li` in the ordered list. BUt I want one of them should not have increment counter:

- 1 should be A
- 2 should be B
- 3 should be C
- 4 should be empty
- but 5 should be D

How can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Two things to do:

1. Add `list-style-type: none` to the 4th `li` (BTW, a `p` inside an `li` is not valid HTML, jsut nest the `ul` in there)
2. For the "D" numbering at the fifth `li`, *end* (= close) the `ol` before that `li` and start a new `ol` with the following attributes: `<ol style="list-style-type: upper-alpha;" start="4">`

```css
.notCounted {
  list-style-type: none
}
```

```html
<ol style="list-style-type: upper-alpha;">
  <li>ALICI; mal satışına ilişkin mesafeli sözleşmelerde, ürünün kendisine veya gösterdiği adresteki kişi/kuruluşa teslim tarihinden itibaren kanunen 14 (ondört) gün  içerisinde hiçbir hukuki ve cezai sorumluluk üstlenmeksizin ve hiçbir gerekçe göstermeksizin
    malı reddederek sözleşmeden cayma hakkını kullanabilir. Hizmet sunumuna ilişkin mesafeli sözleşmelerde ise, bu süre sözleşmenin imzalandığı tarihten itibaren başlar. Cayma hakkının kullanımından kaynaklanan masraflar SATICI’ya aittir.</li>
  <li>ALICI, mesafeli sözleşmeyi ya da buna karşılık gelen herhangi bir teklifi kabul etmeden önce işbu Ön Bilgilendirme Formu ile SATICI tarafından bilgilendirildiğini peşinen kabul eder.</li>
  <li>Cayma hakkının kullanılması için 14 (ondört) günlük süre içinde SATICI'ya iadeli taahhütlü posta, faks veya eposta ile SATICI’nın yukarıda belirtilen adresine yazılı bildirimde bulunulması gerekmektedir. Ancak ilgili hukuki düzenlemeler gereğince aşağıda
    yazılı mal/hizmetlere ilişkin sözleşmelerde, kullanılmamış/istifade edilmemiş olsa dahi, cayma hakkı bulunmamaktadır: <br /> <br /> ALICI’nın özel istekleri veya onun kişisel ihtiyaçları doğrultusunda üretilen (üzerinde değişiklik ya da ilaveler yapılarak
    kişiye/kişisel ihtiyaçlara özel hale getirilenler dahil) mallar;  niteliği itibariyle geri gönderilmeye elverişli olmayan ve çabuk bozulma tehlikesi olan veya son kullanma tarihi geçme ihtimali olan mallar; ALICI tarafından ambalajı açılmış cd, dvd
    gibi ses veya görüntü kayıtları, yazılım programları ve bilgisayar sarf malzemeleri; fiyatı borsa gibi teşkilatlanmış piyasalarda belirlenen mallar; gazete, dergi gibi yayınlar; bahis ve piyangoya ilişkin hizmetler; genel olarak, elektronik ortamda
    anında ifa edilen tüm hizmetler ve ALICI’ya anında teslim edilen her türlü gayri maddi mallar. Ayrıca, ALICI onayı ile cayma hakkı süresi içinde ifasına başlanan hizmetler ve ilgili mevzuat uyarınca mesafeli satış kapsamı dışında kabul edilen diğer
    mal-hizmetler.
  </li>
  <li class="notCounted">
    <!--This item should not have an increment counter but next item should have in orderly -->
      <ul style="list-style-type: none">
        <li>
          Cayma hakkı süresinin belirlenmesinde;<br />
          <ul style="list-style-type: none">
            <li>Tek sipariş konusu olup ayrı ayrı teslim edilen mallarda, tüketicinin veya tüketici tarafından belirlenen üçüncü kişinin son malı teslim aldığı gün,</li>
            <li>Birden fazla parçadan oluşan mallarda, tüketicinin veya tüketici tarafından belirlenen üçüncü kişinin son parçayı teslim aldığı gün,</li>
            <li>Belirli bir süre boyunca malın düzenli tesliminin yapıldığı sözleşmelerde, tüketicinin veya tüketici tarafından belirlenen üçüncü kişinin ilk malı teslim aldığı gün esas alınır.</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  </ol>
  <ol style="list-style-type: upper-alpha;" start="4">
  <li>
    Cayma hakkının kullanılması halinde,
    <ol style="list-style-type: lower-roman;">
      <li>3. kişiye veya ALICI’ya teslim edilen ürünün faturası, (İade edilmek istenen ürünün faturası kurumsal ise, geri iade ederken kurumun düzenlemiş olduğu iade faturası ile birlikte gönderilmesi gerekmektedir. Faturası kurumlar adına düzenlenen sipariş
        iadeleri İADE FATURASI kesilmediği takdirde tamamlanamayacaktır.)</li>
      <li>İade formu</li>
      <li>İade edilecek ürünlerin kutusu, ambalajı, varsa standart aksesuarları ile birlikte eksiksiz ve hasarsız olarak teslim edilmesi gerekmektedir.</li>
      <li>SATICI, cayma bildiriminin kendisine ulaşmasından itibaren en geç 14 günlük süre içerisinde toplam bedeli ve ALICI’yı borç altına sokan belgeleri ALICI’ya iade etmek ve 20 günlük süre içerisinde malı iade almakla yükümlüdür.</li>
      <li>ALICI’nın kusurundan kaynaklanan bir nedenle malın değerinde bir azalma olursa veya iade imkânsızlaşırsa ALICI kusuru oranında SATICI’nın zararlarını tazmin etmekle yükümlüdür.</li>
      <li>Cayma hakkının kullanılması nedeniyle SATICI tarafından düzenlenen kampanya limit tutarının altına düşülmesi halinde kampanya kapsamında faydalanılan indirim miktarı iptal edilir.</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `list-style-type:none` property:

```css
#notNumbered {
  list-style-type: none
}
```

```html
<ol style="list-style-type: upper-alpha;">
  <li>ALICI; mal satışına ilişkin mesafeli sözleşmelerde, ürünün kendisine veya gösterdiği adresteki kişi/kuruluşa teslim tarihinden itibaren kanunen 14 (ondört) gün  içerisinde hiçbir hukuki ve cezai sorumluluk üstlenmeksizin ve hiçbir gerekçe göstermeksizin
    malı reddederek sözleşmeden cayma hakkını kullanabilir. Hizmet sunumuna ilişkin mesafeli sözleşmelerde ise, bu süre sözleşmenin imzalandığı tarihten itibaren başlar. Cayma hakkının kullanımından kaynaklanan masraflar SATICI’ya aittir.</li>
  <li>ALICI, mesafeli sözleşmeyi ya da buna karşılık gelen herhangi bir teklifi kabul etmeden önce işbu Ön Bilgilendirme Formu ile SATICI tarafından bilgilendirildiğini peşinen kabul eder.</li>
  <li>Cayma hakkının kullanılması için 14 (ondört) günlük süre içinde SATICI'ya iadeli taahhütlü posta, faks veya eposta ile SATICI’nın yukarıda belirtilen adresine yazılı bildirimde bulunulması gerekmektedir. Ancak ilgili hukuki düzenlemeler gereğince aşağıda
    yazılı mal/hizmetlere ilişkin sözleşmelerde, kullanılmamış/istifade edilmemiş olsa dahi, cayma hakkı bulunmamaktadır: <br /> <br /> ALICI’nın özel istekleri veya onun kişisel ihtiyaçları doğrultusunda üretilen (üzerinde değişiklik ya da ilaveler yapılarak
    kişiye/kişisel ihtiyaçlara özel hale getirilenler dahil) mallar;  niteliği itibariyle geri gönderilmeye elverişli olmayan ve çabuk bozulma tehlikesi olan veya son kullanma tarihi geçme ihtimali olan mallar; ALICI tarafından ambalajı açılmış cd, dvd
    gibi ses veya görüntü kayıtları, yazılım programları ve bilgisayar sarf malzemeleri; fiyatı borsa gibi teşkilatlanmış piyasalarda belirlenen mallar; gazete, dergi gibi yayınlar; bahis ve piyangoya ilişkin hizmetler; genel olarak, elektronik ortamda
    anında ifa edilen tüm hizmetler ve ALICI’ya anında teslim edilen her türlü gayri maddi mallar. Ayrıca, ALICI onayı ile cayma hakkı süresi içinde ifasına başlanan hizmetler ve ilgili mevzuat uyarınca mesafeli satış kapsamı dışında kabul edilen diğer
    mal-hizmetler.
  </li>
  <li id="notNumbered">
    <!--This item should not have an increment counter but next item should have in orderly -->
    <p>
      <ul style="list-style-type: none">
        <li>
          Cayma hakkı süresinin belirlenmesinde;<br />
          <ul style="list-style-type: none">
            <li>Tek sipariş konusu olup ayrı ayrı teslim edilen mallarda, tüketicinin veya tüketici tarafından belirlenen üçüncü kişinin son malı teslim aldığı gün,</li>
            <li>Birden fazla parçadan oluşan mallarda, tüketicinin veya tüketici tarafından belirlenen üçüncü kişinin son parçayı teslim aldığı gün,</li>
            <li>Belirli bir süre boyunca malın düzenli tesliminin yapıldığı sözleşmelerde, tüketicinin veya tüketici tarafından belirlenen üçüncü kişinin ilk malı teslim aldığı gün esas alınır.</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    Cayma hakkının kullanılması halinde,
    <ol style="list-style-type: lower-roman;">
      <li>3. kişiye veya ALICI’ya teslim edilen ürünün faturası, (İade edilmek istenen ürünün faturası kurumsal ise, geri iade ederken kurumun düzenlemiş olduğu iade faturası ile birlikte gönderilmesi gerekmektedir. Faturası kurumlar adına düzenlenen sipariş
        iadeleri İADE FATURASI kesilmediği takdirde tamamlanamayacaktır.)</li>
      <li>İade formu</li>
      <li>İade edilecek ürünlerin kutusu, ambalajı, varsa standart aksesuarları ile birlikte eksiksiz ve hasarsız olarak teslim edilmesi gerekmektedir.</li>
      <li>SATICI, cayma bildiriminin kendisine ulaşmasından itibaren en geç 14 günlük süre içerisinde toplam bedeli ve ALICI’yı borç altına sokan belgeleri ALICI’ya iade etmek ve 20 günlük süre içerisinde malı iade almakla yükümlüdür.</li>
      <li>ALICI’nın kusurundan kaynaklanan bir nedenle malın değerinde bir azalma olursa veya iade imkânsızlaşırsa ALICI kusuru oranında SATICI’nın zararlarını tazmin etmekle yükümlüdür.</li>
      <li>Cayma hakkının kullanılması nedeniyle SATICI tarafından düzenlenen kampanya limit tutarının altına düşülmesi halinde kampanya kapsamında faydalanılan indirim miktarı iptal edilir.</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```